# Append a text to all files under specific folder

Tags: linux, sed, terminal, centos, cpanel

I need to append text to the bottom of the files into .htaccess files under /home directory for all of my client's website.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`
```

I already tried to `echo 'code' >> .htaccess` and failed because it contains new line, I've also tried `\n` or `\r` without success and I'm using `printf`; I can add new line but it says

```
bash: printf: `}': invalid format character
```

Update..

Im successfully fix the invalid format character by following tripleee code but unfortunately it not append all of my .htaccess files

This is the code

```
for file in /home/*/public_html/.htaccess; do
    printf '%s\n' '# Redirect to https' \
        'RewriteEngine On' \
        'RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off' \
        'RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}' >>".htaccess"
done
```

Im able to resolved the issue by using these code

```
printf '%s\n' '# Redirect to https' \
        'RewriteEngine On' \
        'RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off' \
        'RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}'  |
tee -a /home/*/public_html/.htaccess
```

Thanks to tripleee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to double the `%` to produce a literal per-cent character in a `printf` format string.  Or, pass an explicit format string to `printf` and pass the individual lines as arguments.

```sh
printf '%s\n' 'RewriteEngine On' \
        'RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off' \
        'RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}' |
tee -a /home/*/public_html/.htaccess >/dev/null
```

There's no reason you couldn't use `echo` too, though it's slightly hard on the eyes.

```sh
echo 'RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}' |
tee -a /home/*/public_html/.htaccess >/dev/null
```

You can get something similar with `echo -e` but it's less portable and less elegant than `printf`.

You could also simply use a here document:

```sh
tee -a /home/*/public_html/.htaccess<<-'____HERE' >/dev/null
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
____HERE
```

Putting a dash (minus) before the here-document separator allows you to use tabs (but not spaces!) for indentation; the leading tabs will be stripped from the text. Putting quotes around the separator causes the shell to quote the document (i.e. no dollar signs or backticks in the document will be evaluated).

Comment: Oh, your code updates the file `.htaccess` in the current directory, not the one you are looping over. You should take care to actually copy the code from the answer (though I have subsequently updated it; try the updated version first).